Getting the error while running the new app of react-native
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/.cxx/Debug/3c1ax5u6/arm64-v8a' [0/2] Re-checking globbed directories... [1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp.o FAILED: CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp.o /Users/digittrix/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=/Users/digittrix/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -Dappmodules_EXPORTS -I/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup -I/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/eb4b98dea289284ca2b26e9265bd49ab/transformed/fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/jsi/include -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=cpp -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++20 -DLOG_TAG="ReactNative" -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp.o -c /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp:9: In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.h:15: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorProviderRegistry.h:13: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorProvider.h:10: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/ComponentDescriptor.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/Props.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/PropsMacros.h:11: /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/utils/fnv1a.h:24:37: error: no type named 'identity' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'folly::Identity'? template  ^~~~~ /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/folly/Utility.h:339:7: note: 'folly::Identity' declared here using Identity = identity_fn; ^ In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.cpp:9: In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/autolinking.h:15: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorProviderRegistry.h:13: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorProvider.h:10: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/ComponentDescriptor.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/Props.h:14: /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/RawProps.h:141:38: error: expected concept name with optional arguments { T::filterRawProps(rawProps) } -> std::same_as; ^ 2 errors generated. [2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/OnLoad.cpp.o FAILED: CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/OnLoad.cpp.o /Users/digittrix/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=/Users/digittrix/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -Dappmodules_EXPORTS -I/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup -I/Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/eb4b98dea289284ca2b26e9265bd49ab/transformed/fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/jsi/include -isystem /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=cpp -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++20 -DLOG_TAG="ReactNative" -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/OnLoad.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/OnLoad.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/appmodules.dir/OnLoad.cpp.o -c /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/OnLoad.cpp In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/OnLoad.cpp:30: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/DefaultComponentsRegistry.h:11: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/fabric/ComponentFactory.h:11: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorFactory.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/ComponentDescriptor.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/Props.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/PropsMacros.h:11: /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/utils/fnv1a.h:24:37: error: no type named 'identity' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'folly::Identity'? template  ^~~~~ /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/folly/Utility.h:339:7: note: 'folly::Identity' declared here using Identity = identity_fn; ^ In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/OnLoad.cpp:30: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/DefaultComponentsRegistry.h:11: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/fabric/ComponentFactory.h:11: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/componentregistry/ComponentDescriptorFactory.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/ComponentDescriptor.h:12: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/Props.h:14: /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/RawProps.h:141:38: error: expected concept name with optional arguments { T::filterRawProps(rawProps) } -> std::same_as; ^ In file included from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/OnLoad.cpp:30: In file included from /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/DefaultComponentsRegistry.h:14: /Users/digittrix/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/reactnative/include/react/renderer/core/ConcreteComponentDescriptor.h:109:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RawPropsFilterable' if constexpr (RawPropsFilterable) { ^ 3 errors generated. ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. C++ build system [build] failed while executing: /Users/digittrix/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \ -C \ /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app/.cxx/Debug/3c1ax5u6/arm64-v8a \ appmodules from /Users/digittrix/Desktop/Homzkart/android/app

I am not getting what's happening while running the app.
i am expecting that app may run but it's not

You have 3 errors, read your error log to find them.  Look at the files mentioned.  Then post the code that it was executing that caused the errors so someone can help you fix it, otherwise its a bring arms in the arm shrug from the Stackoverflow community.  NOTE - when I say post the code, it needs to be in text form, not a picture so someone can edit it.  Good luck!
